# How to compare two values in Realm Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I have a `Realm` database called `NewsCount`. I need to download a new news only if there is a new news (respectively when `newsCount` change). And I make a comparison with the data parsing. But I can not compare them properly. How do you compare them?

[image: myImage]

Thi is my code

```
private func parseJSONData(_ data: Data) {
do {
    let temp: NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
    let myNSData = temp.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!

    guard let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myNSData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary else {
        return
    }
    guard let jsonNews = jsonResult["categories"] as? [AnyObject] else {
        print("Empty array")
        return
    }

    let realm = try Realm()
    let category = realm.objects(NewsCount.self)
    var array = [Int]()

    for i in category {
        array.append(i.newsCount)
    }

    print(array)
    print("News COUNT2 \(category)")

    for jsonnewes in jsonNews {
        let newsJson = NewsCount()

        //HERE I COMPARE
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "AppStarted") || jsonnewes["count"] as! Int > array[jsonnewes as! Int]{
            newsJson.newsID = jsonnewes["term_id"] as! Int
            newsJson.newsCount = jsonnewes["count"] as! Int
            //print("News COUNT2 \(newsJson.newsCount)")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "downloadNew"), object: nil)
        } else {
            newsJson.newsID = jsonnewes["term_id"] as! Int
            newsJson.newsCount = jsonnewes["count"] as! Int
            //print("News COUNT3 \(newsJson.newsCount)")
        }

        insertOrUpdate(newsJson)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Realm uses RealmOptional to use Int values you have to call the value atribute to the RealmOptional

Try change this:

```
for i in category {
        array.append(i.newsCount.value)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's probably more appropriate to use `Int(string)` instead of `as! Int` force-casting to convert your JSON data to integers.

From the looks of it, `jsonnewes` is a dictionary full of JSON data, but you're casting it as an array index in `array[jsonnewes as! Int]` which (given `array` is an array and not a dictionary) shouldn't work.

Instead, in order to make sure you're explicitly retrieving the item you want, I'd recommend using [Realm's primary key query method](https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.3.0/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6objectu0_RxCS_6ObjectrFT6ofTypeMx13forPrimaryKeyq__GSqx_) in order to retrieve the item you want.

```
let realm = try! Realm()

for newsItem in jsonNews {
    let newsPrimaryKey = Int(newsItem)
    let realmNews = realm.object(ofType: NewsCount.self, forPrimaryKey: newsPrimaryKey)

    // Don't continue if a Realm object couldn't be found
    guard let realmNews = realmNews else {
        continue
    }    

    // Perform comparison
    if Int(newsItem["count"]) > realmNews.newsCount {
        // Perform the update
    }
}
```